# selenium error when trying to make automate translation with google

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to write an automation of translation with google to do translation of my list of contents, which has around 1000 rows. The browser that I'm using is Chrome.

The content that I am trying to translate is from Chinese to English. Some of first few content, I am able to run the code. However, I have found out that when the code has been run for a while, it seems it unable to recognize some Chinese characters and it returns me the following picture. My Chinese input has turn to some unrecognized code.

[image]

Also, when I try to make sure that my input is in string

```
(example: 
browser.get("https://translate.google.com/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=" + str(i) + "&op=translate"))
```

I end up with the following error after it has been run for a while. I don't know why some string work with my code and some doesn't. Below is the error that I received:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".HwtZe"}
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x01147413+2389011]
    Ordinal0 [0x010D9F61+1941345]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FCC658+837208]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FF91DD+1020381]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FF949B+1021083]
    Ordinal0 [0x01026032+1204274]
    Ordinal0 [0x01014194+1130900]
    Ordinal0 [0x01024302+1196802]
    Ordinal0 [0x01013F66+1130342]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FEE546+976198]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FEF456+980054]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012F9632+1727522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x013ABA4D+2457661]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x011DEB81+569713]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x011DDD76+566118]
    Ordinal0 [0x010E0B2B+1968939]
    Ordinal0 [0x010E5988+1989000]
    Ordinal0 [0x010E5A75+1989237]
    Ordinal0 [0x010EECB1+2026673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76B900F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D27BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D27B8E+238]
```

And this is my code:

```
content_output = []
for i in content:
    if len(i)>1500:
        sep_cons = i.split()
        combine_con = []
        for sep_con in sep_cons:
            browser = webdriver.Chrome()
            browser.implicitly_wait(10)
            browser.get("https://translate.google.com/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=" + sep_con + "&op=translate")
            time.sleep(random.randint(5,10))
            result = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"HwtZe").text
            combine_con.append(result)
            browser.close()
        combine_con = [' '.join(combine_con)]
        content_output.append(combine_con)
    else:
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.implicitly_wait(10)
        browser.get("https://translate.google.com/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=" + i + "&op=translate")
        time.sleep(random.randint(5,10))
        result = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"HwtZe").text
        content_output.append(result)
        browser.close()
```

Comment: please add a working example, the variable `content` is undefined.